# How to use BookmarksManager.Chrome to get bookmark hierarchy?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to use the "BookmarksManager.Chrome" (NuGet package).
I've been able to read the bookmarks with ChromeBookmarksReader.Read. But I need to display the bookmarkstructure in a tree and I haven't found a way to get the bookmarks id and parentid.
Does anyone know how to do this?
The ChromeBookmarkModel seems to have all the information. But how to use it? There is no way to convert a BookmarkFolder to the ChromeBookmarkModel ...

Best regards, Tom

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) instead of BookmarksManager nuget.
I tried achieving the same thing as you, but had no luck using the BookmarksManager nuget. Luckily I was able to find a way of displaying the folder hierarchy using Html Agility Pack. Admittedly my solution is for WPF but I'm sure its no big deal to rewrite it to WinForms.

**1. Use Html Agility Pack to remove all Tags that prevent the File from being a valid XML and therefore prevent us from reading the structure correctly:**

```
    public void OpenBookmarksFile()
    {
        string BookmarksFile_w_impeding_tags = @"your_bookmarks_file.html";
        BuildTree(treeView, XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), (DeleteTags(BookmarksFile_w_impeding_tags)))));
    }

    public string DeleteTags(string BookmarksFile_w_impeding_tags)
    {
        StreamReader BookmarkDatei = new StreamReader(BookmarksFile_w_impeding_tags);
        string content = BookmarkDatei.ReadToEnd();
        BookmarkDatei.Close();
        HtmlDocument doc_lessTags = new HtmlDocument();

        //deletes all DD Tags
        string DD = "(<DD>[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^<]+)"; //Regex-Pattern
        doc_lessTags.LoadHtml(Regex.Replace(content, DD, ""));

        //variable for each tag that could be impeding for displaying the correct hierarchy
        var metas = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
        var titles = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//title");
        var h1s = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1");
        var dts = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dt");
        var ps = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
        var hrs = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//hr");
        var dds = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd");
        var aa = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
        var h3s = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3");

        //delete all tags that could be impeding (comments too)
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var doctype = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/comment()[starts-with(.,'<!DOCTYPE')]");
        if (doctype != null)
        {
            doctype.Remove();
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var comments = doc_lessTags.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()");
        if (comments != null)
        {
            comments.Remove();
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        foreach (var meta in metas)
        {
            meta.Remove();
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        foreach (var title in titles)
        {
            title.Remove();
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        foreach (var h1 in h1s)
        {
            h1.Remove();
        }
        //-----some(open tags, like DT) can not be deleted the normal way becaue they would reverse the order of our file------
        if (dts != null)
        {
            foreach (var dt in dts)
            {
                if (!dt.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    dt.ParentNode.RemoveChild(dt);
                    continue;
                }

                for (var i = dt.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var child = dt.ChildNodes[i];
                    dt.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, dt);
                }
                dt.ParentNode.RemoveChild(dt);
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (ps != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in ps)
            {
                if (!p.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    p.ParentNode.RemoveChild(p);
                    continue;
                }

                for (var i = p.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var child = p.ChildNodes[i];
                    p.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, p);
                }
                p.ParentNode.RemoveChild(p);
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (hrs != null)
        {
            foreach (var hr in hrs)
            {
                if (!hr.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    hr.ParentNode.RemoveChild(hr);
                    continue;
                }

                for (var i = hr.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var child = hr.ChildNodes[i];
                    hr.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, hr);
                }
                hr.ParentNode.RemoveChild(hr);
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (dds != null)
        {
            foreach (var dd in dds)
            {
                if (!dd.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    dd.ParentNode.RemoveChild(dd);
                    continue;
                }

                for (var i = dd.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var child = dd.ChildNodes[i];
                    dd.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, dd);
                }
                dd.ParentNode.RemoveChild(dd);
            }
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //system partition
        string sysPart = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
        //currently logged in user
        string userName = Environment.UserName;


        //after deleting all impeding tags we save the result to a new file so that we can keep our original file untouched
        string BookmarksFile_less_tags = $@"{sysPart}Users\{userName}\Desktop\bookmarks_less_tags";
        doc_lessTags.Save(BookmarksFile_less_tags);

        return BookmarksFile_less_tags;
    }
```

**2. Use the newly created File with System.Xml; and System.Xml.Linq; to populate the TreeView**

```
 public void BuildTree(TreeView treeView, XDocument doc)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeNode = new TreeViewItem
        {
            //Should be Root
            Header = doc.Root.Name.LocalName,
            IsExpanded = true
        };
        treeView.Items.Add(treeNode);
        BuildNodes(treeNode, doc.Root);
    }

    public void BuildNodes(TreeViewItem treeNode, XElement element)
    {
        foreach (XNode child in element.Nodes())
        {
            switch (child.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    XElement childElement = child as XElement;
                    XElement prev = child.PreviousNode as XElement;
                    if(childElement.Name == "dl" && prev.Name == "h3")
                    { 

                        TreeViewItem childTreeNode = new TreeViewItem
                        {
                            //because only the dl nodes have child nodes we want 
                            //to display the dl nodes with the inner text of thier respective previous node
                            Header = prev.Value
                        };

                        treeNode.Items.Add(childTreeNode);
                        BuildNodes(childTreeNode, childElement);
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    XText childText = child as XText;
                    treeNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = childText.Value, });
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[if you don't add any icons it will look something like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Uob.png)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't very detailed.

However, the code is overally tiny enough to (partially) replace the documentation:

```
public class BookmarkFolder : Collection<IBookmarkItem>, IBookmarkFolder
```

In other words: Each folder you get in itself *is* a collection containing its sub-items (folders and links):

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead(path)) {
    var reader = new NetscapeBookmarksReader();
    var bookmarks = reader.Read(file);
    foreach (var item in bookmarks) {
        if (item is BookmarkFolder) {
        } else if (item is BookmarkLink) {
        }
        ....
```

See https://github.com/Dissimilis/BookmarksManager/blob/master/BookmarksManager/BookmarkFolder.cs#L8